# Volume of solid generated when revolving around a line

Tags: calculus

The question asks to find the volume of a solid generated when the region bounded by the curves $y_1=\frac{12}{x}+6$, $y_2=0$, $x_1=2$, $x_2=8$ is revolved around the line $x=12$.
I have watched some videos on this topic and I understand there is a disk and shell method, and on this one since the line of revolution is a vertical line I am pretty sure you have to use the method that uses $dy$. I tried using the $π\int R(y)^2dy$ however I am unsure how to compute the proper limits of integration with the $y$ values. I also don't understand how to find the radius with $y=0$,and I think I am failing to comprehend the subject but also the $y=0$ is throwing me off since I cannot make it into $x$ being a function of $y$. Sorry my understanding is limited but any help is appreciated, I think once I see the question worked out with proper steps I will understand better.

Comment: So you wish to use the disk method by integrating along $y$, and to invert $y_1 = (12/x) + 6$ to be a function of $y$? Then $y=0$ is one of the limits of integration.

Comment: So would you say the radius would be (x-12) since that is the axis of rotation, then you could plug y into the x value and then integrate from 0 to the other limit of integration?

Comment: If you integrate with respect to $y$ you will have an annulus for a cross wection so it will be $\pi\int R^2-r^2\,dy$ and $r$ will be constant for $0\le y\le7.5$ and variable for $7.5<y\le12$, so you have to break it into two integrals over those intervals. It might be easier to integrate with respect to $x$ and use the cylindrical shell method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating with respect to $x$ rather than with respect to $y$ will give cylindrical cross section as in the diagram:

[image: Diagram of solid of revolution with cylindrical cross sections]

Then using surface area formula for a cylinder $A=2\pi rh$ the volume can be found using $r=12-x$ and $h=f(x)=\frac{12}{x}+6$

So

$$ V=2\pi\int_2^8(12-x)\left(\frac{12}{x}+6\right)dx $$

Here is a [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pnrfyzv5pc) construction.

Comment: How would the shape be different by integrating with respect to y? Or rather, how do you know how to draw the shape, other than that the rest of the answer makes sense and I appreciate the visualization.

Comment: Integrating with respect to $y$ you would take cross sections of the solid parallel to the base of the solid. So each cross section would be an annulus.